Are Christians ignoring that Jesus was to be from King David's line and not Yahweh's line?
Are Christians ignoring that Jesus was to be from King David's line and not Yahweh's?

No  Christians are not ignoring that

This Question is unclear; what is meant by "Yahweh's line" and why is there a supposed issue? (Note: Adam is often named "the son of God", which would suggest that Jesus is "from Yahweh's line"... also, Noah's, Shem's, Abraham's, Jesse's, and many others; including, of course, David.)

Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange. Please take our tour to understand what we look for in well thought-out and researched questions.  It helps if people can understand what you are asking and the basis for asking it.  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Does your question have anything to do with the views of the House of Yahweh?

This question has not given any consideration to other contributors as there is not enough information to be able to answer it.

Yawheh and David are not comparable by any means, Yawheh is God , He begets children through the Holy Spirit even born again Christians, David is flesh, he begets children by biological means.

Jesus is the very Son of God, begotten and not created, and who existed in heaven alongside his Father from before the founding of the world.
This answer to a recent question might give you some insights: Where in the New Testament is God described as a Yahweh?
However, since your question is unclear - we do not know what you mean by "Yahwey's line" - then it would be helpful if you explain what you are trying to get at.
